# Sleep in loop when application is running, but sleeps too few

Tags: c#, sleep, thread-sleep

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        TemporaryCityTool.TemporaryCityTool.AddCity();
        Console.WriteLine("waiting...");
        Thread.Sleep(3600);
    }
}
```

why `Thread.sleep` not working. I am getting message waiting all the time. I want that application will wait 10 minutes then continue again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**[`Thread.Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx)** takes a value in milliseconds, not seconds, so this only tells the current thread to wait 3.6 seconds. If you want to wait 10 minutes, use:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 10);  // 600,000 ms = 600 sec = 10 min
```

This is probably an inappropriate use of `Sleep`, though. Consider using a Timer instead, so that you get something along the lines of:

```
// Fire SomeAction() every 10 minutes.
Timer timer = new Timer(o => SomeAction(), null, 10 * 60 * 1000, -1);
```

See **[this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391621/compare-using-thread-sleep-and-timer-for-delayed-execution)** for more details on that.

Answer (score 3):

The argument of the [Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) method is in milliseconds, so if you want to sleep for 10 minutes:

```
Thread.Sleep(10 * 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

10 minutes in milliseconds is 600,000.  Your Sleep will only wait 3.6 seconds.  It's often clearer to use a timespan:

```
Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0,10,0));
```

Comment: I agree, but you can make it even clearer using the static factory method "FromMinutes(10)" :)

Answer (score 2):

3600 is 3.6 seconds. If you want it to sleep for 10 minutes, you should set it to 600000.

```
Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 10);  // Milliseconds(1000) * Seconds(60) * Minutes(10)
```

Which is equal to:

```
Thread.Sleep(600000);
```

Answer (score 1):

thrad.sleep is in milli seconds  10 mins would be thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 10)

Why are you using thread.sleep, you may be better using a timer

Answer (score -1):

thx, my big mistake. 
John Feminella i use thread now.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread thrd1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Trmain));

            thrd1.Start();
        }

        private static void Trmain()
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("waiting 10 minutes...");
                Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 10);
            }
        }
```

thx all

Comment: You should accept the answer that helped the most by clicking the Tick next to the question. And you should have posted the above as an edit to your original question.