# How to Execute Command/function in Asp.net Automatically To send Email / Sms Without user logged In

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [doing scheduled background work in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645302/doing-scheduled-background-work-in-asp-net)

I want To Send Email/SMS To my user Automatically in Asp.net C#, even they are not logged In.

I want To do : On Birthday Of User Automatically send Email/Sms To Users To say Happy Birthday.

Example of running site: Way2SmS.com send User Sms automatically on Their Birthday Also Way2Sms send SMS automatically When user set it to send(user provide date & time).

Can You please help me regarding this.?

Is any possibilities of doing this.?

If yes please provide me some code or link or details. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better of with a console application that you schedule, or a windows service.
Otherwise, you have to keep your website 'alive' and use the Timer etc. That's more like a workaround.

Best solution is in my view a Windows Service that can periodically check the date and your database and perform the actions required. Nobody needs to be logged-in. You could even run the service on a different machine if you are worried about load.

Comment: +1: This type of thing is exactly what a Windows service or the built in windows task scheduling app is for.  Using timers on websites is just bad.